# The C# MVC 3 Routing want to add hard code word also in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

The C# MVC 3 Routing i have a controller name Category.
There are 2 Sub Method of the Controller 
1)Index
2)Detail

now my detail routing URl coming like this "Category/name" ok but i also want to Add "category/Name-for-all" hard code "-for-all"
 want to add this hard code how ?

```
    routes.MapRoute(
     "categorie", // Route name
     "Category/{id}/{no}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Category", action = "details", id = "id",no=UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
 );
    routes.MapRoute(
       "categories", // Route name
       "Category/{id}/{action}", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Category", action = "action", id = "id" } // Parameter defaults
   );



html page

<div class="grid_3" >
    <a class="companyanchor" href="/category/@Model.name/">@Model.Name</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to understand your question, as I understand you asking about hard coded part of url? Something like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(null,
    "{category}/Page{page}", // Matches /Football/Page567 
    new { controller = "Product", action = "List" }, // Defaults
    new { page = @"\d+" } // Constraints: page must be numerical
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with MVC recently, but isn't this the answer?

```
routes.MapRoute("categories", // Route name        
    "Category/{id}"-for-all/{action}", // URL with parameters        
    new { controller = "Category", action = "action", id = "id" } // Parameter defaults    
);
```

... not sure where "Name" comes from in your example.